# Getting Scene2D Actor's position after rotating in Libgdx

Tags: math, geometry, libgdx, scene2d

I have the following rotation function:

```
public void rotate( Actor a ) {
    float rotateBy = 30.0f,
          newX = ( a.getX() * ( float ) Math.cos( rotateBy ) ) - ( a.getY() * ( float ) Math.sin( rotateBy ) ),
          newY = ( a.getX() * ( float ) Math.sin( rotateBy ) ) + ( a.getY() * ( float ) Math.cos( rotateBy ) ),
          moveByX = a.getX() - newX, // delta
          moveByY = a.getY() - newY, // delta
          duration = 1.0f; // 1 second

    a.addAction(
        Actions.sequence(
            Actions.parallel(
                Actions.rotateBy( rotateBy, duration ),
                Actions.moveBy( moveByX, moveByY, duration )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

But it seems the **moveByX** and **moveByY** values are not accurate.

The goal is to figure out what the new x,y would be after rotation, and move up by that much so that it still maintains the same y as before it was rotated.

[image: Desired result]

Also, my Actor's draw method:

```
    @Override
    public void draw( Batch batch, float parentAlpha ) {
        batch.draw( texture, getX(), getY(), getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, getWidth(), getHeight(), getScaleX(), getScaleY(), getRotation() );
    }
```

Comment: Are you rotating around the center of the box then translating?  Your vertex positions would need to be relative to the center of the box if you want a simple rotation without translation.

Comment: Sorry, not really following your question. Are you familiar with LibGDX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I would do it: first the origin of the actor must be the center of the square, then rotate the actor on its center and you will see something like this

[image: problem]

The red line represent the y-offset that the actor needs to be moved up in order to follow the floor, as you can see this y-offset increases and  decreases (so maybe you can't use Actions.moveBy because this move it along a linear way and your path isn't linear, see the blue line) so

```
Vector2 pos = new Vector2();
public void rotate(float delta, Actor a) {
    a.rotateBy(angularSpeed*delta);
    pos.x += linearSpeed*delta;
    a.setPosition(pos.x,pos.y+yOffset(a.getRotation());
}
```

yOffset is the function that describes the lenght of the red line based on the square rotation angle:

```
public float yOffset(float angle) {
    angle %= Math.PI/2;
    return (float) Math.abs(squareSize*(Math.sin((Math.PI/4+angle))-Math.sin(Math.PI/4)));
}
```

All angles are in radians.

Comment: yes this is exactly what I'm trying to do, but the part that you left out is exactly the part that I am asking about :)  How to calculate the y offset after rotation?

Comment: I've added the yOffset implementation

Comment: great! One question: how to handle shapes that don't have the same width and height? Like an oval or rectangle?